# multiple default values specified for column "id" of table "Transaction"

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to deploy a Django app to Heroku, and the moment I start doing the migrations with these commands:
`heroku run python manage.py makemigrations`
`heroku run python manage.py migrate`

I get the following error, here's the full stack trace:

```
Running migrations:
  Applying transaction.0004_auto_20210315_0103...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: multiple default values specified for column "id" of table "Transaction"


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 85, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 245, in handle       
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards  
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 227, in apply_migration        
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 106, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 487, in add_field
    self.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 142, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: multiple default values specified for column "id" of table "Transaction"
```

This is the code from my Transaction Model:

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    """Modelo de Transaccion"""
    id = models.CharField(max_length=8, primary_key = True)
    TnType = models.ForeignKey(TransactionType, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=True, null=True,
        related_name='id_tn_type')
    userReceiver = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='user_receiver', blank=True, null=True)
    userTransmitter = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        related_name='user_transmitter', blank=True, null=True)
    amount = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    creationTime = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    concept = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True, null=True)
    STATUS = ( 
        ('A','Active'),
        ('I','Inactive'),
    )
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=STATUS, default='A')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id

    class Meta: 
        db_table = "Transaction"

class TransactionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'userReceiver', 'userTransmitter', 'amount' )
```

I really don't understand this error, I've been trying a lot of things with no luck. I hope someone could help.

This is my: `0004_auto_20210315_0103`

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('transaction', '0003_auto_20210315_0101'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='transaction',
            name='idTransaction',
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='transaction',
            name='id',
            field=models.AutoField(auto_created=True, default='1', primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID'),
            preserve_default=False,
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: Please add the full stack trace of the error to your question.

Comment: Done, I just added it.

Comment: Please show the migration file `0004_auto_20210315_0103`.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I added the code of that file.

Comment: Looking at your migration files you added an `AutoField` with a `default`. This doesn't make much sense as an `AutoField` increments automatically so a default for it is not sensible (the same giving you an error), plus a default for a primary key is not correct anyway. Simply remove the `default='1'` from the migration

Comment: Omg, thanks so much, that worked!